# TabControl width increases on adding tabs

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, tabcontrol, scrollviewer

My application UI is divided in 2 parts. Left side is Navigation Menu and Right is View Area where the selected Menu content is displayed. Now, one of the menu is reports. I am using Tabcontrol with Header and Content Template. Template has a ViewModel as DataType and content as the respective View which is a UserControl. This TabControl is inside a scrollviewer which is set as horizontal and vertical alignment to stretch.

The user control hosts a ContentPresenter inside a Grid which is bound to a ReportHost which has a reportviewer as child. I am using this ReportViewer to generate reports.

When the user opens a report, it opens in a new tab. It works fine till the number of tabs is such that the tabheaders are contained inside the viewing area. But as soon as more tabs are added, it causes the tabcontrol width to stretch, causing the content area of the tab to stretch and the contentpresenter also stretches causing horizontal scroll to appear.
This finally result in the report to stretch and due to some reason, unknown to me, the report overlaps the Navigation Area of the UI, as if it is not a part of the UI but is overlapping it. The whole report keeps on floating on top of the View Area and Navigation menu on scrolling.

I can fix it by providing the MaxWidth to the ScrollViewer but I don't want to do that. I would like the width of the tabcontroll or the Scrolviewer to be decided purely based on available View Area. How do I do this through the code or XAML without using fixed width.

I am not sure if I was able to explain the situation. Please let me know if more information or clarification is needed. I would be more than happy to provide details.

Edit: Adding Code for information.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TabContent" DataType="{x:Type VM:ReportViewModel}">
  <View:Report/>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="TabHeader" DataType="{x:Type VM:ReportViewModel}">
  <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=TabHeader}"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</DataTemplate>

<ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
  <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap"
        Text="Reports" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,13,0,0" 
        FontSize="18.667" FontFamily="Segoe UI" Foreground="White"/>
    <Border BorderThickness="0" Margin="0,50,0,0" 
        Background="{DynamicResource Brush_HeaderNew}" Height="50" Width="Auto" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding ReportItems}" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,20,0,0" 
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedReportItem}"
        ContentTemplate="{StaticResource TabContent}" 
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TabHeader}"
    />
  </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ScrollViewer` presents to its child an infinitely large area on which to set itself out, because it reasons that it can just offer scrolling if it's bigger than the space available to `ScrollViewer` itself. Because yours has scrolling enabled in both directions, that means the `TabControl` can expand as much as it likes in either direction, and it's not going to be smart enough to know that it's inside a `ScrollViewer` and that you want the tabs to not take advantage of this virtual space.

From the sound of things, you might want to consider moving the `ScrollViewer` within the `TabControl` so that only the contents of the tab is scrollable rather than the whole set. You should be able to do that by modifying the tab content template.

Comment: Wow, that worked. The only thing is that when tabs are more, the tabheaders are shown in multiple rows. But I guess I can live with that. Thanks so much.

Comment: You can fix that if you want, but it involves changing `TabControl`'s template and is kind of complicated. There are articles around the web that will take you through making one which has scrolling tabs or a few other alternatives instead of generating multiple rows.

Comment: I would try to find out but by any chance, if you have a link to an implementation for the same, I would be glad if you can share that.

Comment: This article was quite helpful to me in figuring out how to mess around with `TabControl` and it covers scrolling tab bars as well as extensive visual customisation. http://www.blogs.intuidev.com/post/2010/02/10/TabControlStyling_PartThree.aspx